# Process JARs - keep only resources and variables

Tags: java, android, jar, gradle, proguard

I'm working on Android app and I've passed the 65536 methods limit.

As a workaround we've created dex that contains some of JARs that has more than 10k functions.

We're loading the classes and using reflection to run methods and it works ok.

But...
When building one of the classes from the dex it looks for a resources that it obviously not available and throws an exception.

Can we somehow remove all methods from the JAR and keep only the resources files?

Another question: Could we remove all methods but keep all the classes variables?
(will also make our life much easier..)

Thanks.

Comment: Congrats on passing method limit, I don't know what are you doing but hitting this limit is sign of poor design and OO patterns

Comment: Sometimes you just need to use external API that adds tons of methods and you just can't do much about it...

Comment: Ok, I've managed to keep only the resources :)
But now I'm trying to figure out how to keep the classes members and remove all methods, this way we'll be in the limit. Any ideas?

Comment: I concur poor design.